# change the width & height of ImageButton at runtime in android

Tags: android, height, runtime, width, imagebutton

I have used this code to make a ImageButton & after that i want to change the size of it at run time. Both the codes the written below,

```
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_new"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/untitled3"
    />
```

---

```
 public void scaler1() {
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getWidth();
    int height = display.getHeight();
    btn_new.setMinimumWidth(width/4);
    btn_new.setMinimumHeight(height/6);
}
```

But it is not working please give any solution of it.

This is the actual code i'm using

```
  public void scaler1() {
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getWidth();
    int height = display.getHeight();

    edit_screen.setWidth(width);
    edit_screen.setHeight(height / 6);

    lpsame = (LayoutParams) btn_0.getLayoutParams();
    lpsame.width=width/4;
    lpsame.height=height/6;

    btn_0.setLayoutParams(lpsame);



    LayoutParams lpedit = (LayoutParams) edit_screen.getLayoutParams();
    lpedit.width=width;
    lpedit.height=height/6;

    LayoutParams lpequal = (LayoutParams) btn_0.getLayoutParams();
    lpequal.width=width/2;
    lpequal.height=height/6;

    edit_screen.setLayoutParams(lpedit);


    btn_2.setLayoutParams(lpsame);
    btn_3.setLayoutParams(lpsame);
    btn_4.setLayoutParams(lpsame);
    btn_5.setLayoutParams(lpsame);
    btn_6.setLayoutParams(lpsame);
    btn_7.setLayoutParams(lpsame);
    btn_8.setLayoutParams(lpsame);
    btn_9.setLayoutParams(lpsame);
    btn_add.setLayoutParams(lpsame);
    btn_subtrac.setLayoutParams(lpsame);
    btn_multiply.setLayoutParams(lpsame);
    btn_divide.setLayoutParams(lpsame);
    btn_dot.setLayoutParams(lpsame);
    btn_percentage.setLayoutParams(lpsame);
    btn_CA.setLayoutParams(lpsame);
    btn_back.setLayoutParams(lpsame);
    btn_equal.setLayoutParams(lpequal);

    editParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height/6);
    sameparam= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width/4,height/6);
    equalparam= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width/2,height/6);

    edit_screen.setLayoutParams(editParams);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change properties of a `View` by using `LayoutParams` class

```
LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) btn_new.getLayoutParams();
lp.width = yourWidth;
lp.height = yourHeight;

btn_new.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

**Update**

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(yourWidth, yourHeight);

yourButtons.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: it is showing this error on setWidth() method, The method setWidth(int) is undefined for the type RelativeLayout.LayoutParams

Comment: it is working for 1 ImageButton, bt when i tried it for multiple ImageButton's then, its nt working

Comment: your question doesn't indicate that. BTW show your code, what are you actually doing.

Comment: what do you mean by "it is not working" ? your button s doesn't getting resized ?

Comment: only singlw button getting resized nt all & also thier allignments are also nt properly displayed

Comment: do my updated answer. I was assuming you only need to update single view. getLayoutParams() copies all layout properties (which includes alignments). Hence  you are copying properties of view_0 to all remaining views

Comment: by doing this update it is not follwing the allignments that i coded in xml file like "layout:Below" & "layout:rightOf". all the buttons are showing at top left side at same place

Comment: you need to do that programatically for each of them, because setLayoutParams are overwriting it

Comment: means i have to use addRule() method for every view & thier is no need to set allignments in xml file then???

Comment: Yes, in your code for every view you need to align.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get an instance of your view, before changing its properties

```
ImageButton btn_new = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_new);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = display.getWidth();
        int height = display.getHeight();

    LayoutParams layoutParams = image_new.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.width=width/4;
    layoutParams.height=height/6;

    image_new.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: it is working for 1 ImageButton, bt when i tried it for multiple ImageButton's then, its nt working

Comment: you have to get individual button params  and set the width and height then set the params respectively.,